# How to create a custom UTType and make it enable for UIDocumentPickerViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uidocumentpickervc

I am creating an app in which there are custom file types such as `.xyz` file, which is not part of UTType API.

Here are the case problems:

- I want to create a custom UTType with `xyz` extension.
- While opening file app, only those file should be enable which has extension `.xyz`
- The file with `xyz` extension should show a custom icon on file App.

Comment: You can make your own UTIs. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24958021/document-types-vs-exported-and-imported-utis) and [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/view_controllers/adding_a_document_browser_to_your_app/setting_up_a_document_browser_app).

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uniformtypeidentifiers/uttype/3601077-init

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You should have mentioned the solutions you tried and it did not work for you.

By the way, there are few steps that you can follow:

**Step 1. Create your document type in info.plist**

- Give the name of your file type such as `xyz`
- Define the `type` identifier such as `com.app.xyz`
- Define the file icon against the key `CFBundleTypeIconFiles`

[image]

**Step 2: Define the exported type identifier in info.plist**

- Add the same identifier that we added while defining document type, i.e. `com.app.xyz`
- define your extension `xyz`, `XYZ`

[image]

**Step 3: Now while initialising UIDocumentPickerViewController, use the UTtype with identifier you declared in first two steps:**

```
let xyzUTType = UTType("com.app.xyz")
let documentPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(forOpeningContentTypes: [xyzUTType], asCopy: true)
```