# Registering new extension that opens in own iOS-App

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, swiftui

I created my own filetype "dmate". Assume I exported a .dmate file to iPhones Files. When clicking on that file, it is looking like this - the JSON-Content is displayed:

[image: Display of Filetype]

Now I can click on the share button and open the file in my App DietMate - which works fine:
[image: Sharing the file with my own app]

Problem: I do not want the user to see JSON text but want the Files-App and WhatsApp and so on to open the file immediately in my App without doing a preview.

Here is the relevant part of my plist.info

```
    <key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
            <string>Food</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
        <array>
            <string>dmate.ft.png</string>
            <string>dmate.ft.png</string>
        </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Viewer</string>
            <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
            <string>Owner</string>
            <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>de.example.app.food.dmate</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    
    <key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
            <array>
                <string>public.json</string>
            </array>
            <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
            <string>Food</string>
            <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
            <string>de.example.app.food.dmate</string>
            <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
            <dict>
                <key>public.filename-extension</key>
                <string>dmate</string>
                <key>public.mime-type</key>
                <string>food/x-dmate</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

Does anyone know, how to open my custom filetype in my own app?

Comment: in your `Info.plist` you have `<key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>`, 
maybe you also need `<key>UTImportedTypeDeclarations</key>`.

Comment: Tried that out. Did not change the behaviour. As far of [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24958021/document-types-vs-exported-and-imported-utis) `UTExportedTypeDeclarations` should be okay, if I got that right.

Comment: Did you try to make it conform to public.json ans specify some icon ?

Comment: At least I tried public.json. Didn't try the icon yet, but i will doublecheck.

Comment: So I doublechecked and tried even more. Did not make it. I edited the question to reflect the latest plist.info I am working withl

Answer (score 0):

If you want your app to launch **right away** after tapping the file in the Files app, try adding this key-value pair to your `Info.plist`:

```xml
<key>LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace</key>
<true/>
```

Another thing you could try is to set "Conforms To" to `public.data` instead of `public.json`. This means that the system will no longer assume that your data is JSON, and hopefully stop displaying it that way. It might have some implications on what sharing channels are supported, and I haven’t yet managed to fully wrap my head around this.